# Angular update 8.1 - circular dependency warning

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

Since updating to Angular 8.1 (8.0 worked), I'm getting a circular dependency warning that doesn't really make sense to me.

I have an Injectable Service `SelectService` that is provided in some components. The service is using a class `SelectableItem`. When creating an instance of this class, the service itself is passed as an argument.

```
item = new SelectableItem(
   ...
   this
);
```

The `SelectableItem`class is not Injectable and looks like this.

```
export class SelectableItem {
    constructor(..., public selectService: SelectService) { }
}
```

Now since the 8.1 update i get a circular dependecy warning:

> selectable-item.ts -> select.service.ts -> selectable-item.ts

`SelectableItem` is not a service, how can it be a circular dependency?

Comment: I think the Angular CLI is just right :)

Comment: I think the problem come from how you import class. Can you add it to your question ?

Comment: @MartinChoraine what do you mean by import? The class is imported with `import { SelectableItem } from './../models/selectable-item';` there is not much special about that.

Comment: Ok this is what I wanted to verify. I already meet this issue when using barrel import. But it's not your case

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectService` class should look something like this. With the dependency to `SelectableItem` as a property of the service class.

```
import "SelectAbleItem" from "../selectable-item.ts

@Injectable()
class SelectService {
}

private selectItem: SelectItem;
public get SelectItem():SelectItem { return this.selectItem; }
```

---

Now in the constructor of the `SelectableItem` don't inject the `SelectService` but rather use the injector to provide it.

```
class SelectableItem {
  constructor() {
    const injector = Injector.create([{provide: SelectService, useClass: SelectService, deps: [SelectableItem]]};
    const selectService = injector.get(SelectService);
  }
}
```

I got some code from [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c) and [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable). The code isn't tested and may contain a small glitch but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I still get the same error when using the Injector. The code is [here](https://github.com/Crazyht/ngx-tree-select/tree/dev/src/ngx-tree-select/src), it's not my repo i'm just trying to fix it.